# React Native: Passing data from a screen to a component to another screen using stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I have a issue where i am using stack navigator in  home screen and i am rendering a jobs component in it, in that job component I have a name title. So when job component renders in my homescreen and user clicks on that title I want to take him to a job description screen, but I also want to pass that title data to description screen. 
[image]
Passing data from one screen to another using stack navigator is straight forward. But I am finding it difficult to pass data from one screen to a component to another screen.
I have managed to navigate from one screen to another via the jobs component but not able to pass the data to job description screen via jobs component.

This is how i am rendering jobs component in Homescreen

```
<Jobs
            jobs={this.state.jobs}
            isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}
            description={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate("JobDescription", {
                job: this.state.jobs,
              })
            }
          />
```

This is my jobs component

```
 const Jobs = (props) =>
  props.jobs.map((job) => {
    return (
      <Card key={job.title}>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.description}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    marginLeft: 25,
                    color: "blue",
                    fontSize: 22,
                  }}
                >
                  {job.name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

And this is my job description code sample

```
 const JobDescription = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Headers drawer={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
            {props.navigation.getParam("name")}
          </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are passing the jobs array through the "job" navigation parameter. You might want to pass the job you are tapping in order to get all the related data of the selected job inside the JobsDescription component instead all the jobs array.

Example:

```
 {/* Pass the selected job to the "description" method. */}
  <Jobs
    jobs={this.state.jobs}
    isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}
    description={(selectedJob) =>
      this.props.navigation.navigate("JobDescription", {
        job: this.state.jobs,
        selectedJob
      })
    }
  />
```

```
const Jobs = (props) =>
  props.jobs.map((job) => {
    return (
      <Card key={job.title}>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.description(job)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    marginLeft: 25,
                    color: "blue",
                    fontSize: 22,
                  }}
                >
                  {job.name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

So you can make something like this

```
const JobDescription = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  // Getting the selected job data through the navigation parameter.
  const selectedJob = navigation.getParam("selectedJob");
  return (
    <Container>
      <Headers drawer={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
            {selectedJob.title}
          </Text>
```

Comment: I will try this out